# How to draw a heating element in TikZ

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz, decorations, circuits

I am attempting to re-create a circuit diagram that contains a heating element using *circuitikz* but am having trouble drawing the element itself.

I have tried using the `spring` shape found in section 4.7 of the *circuitikz* manual, and I have also tried using the `snake` path decoration in TikZ, but am having trouble getting a sensible result with both.

I am wondering if someone can help point me in the right direction to draw the shape depicted below, or can provide an example that I can adapt for my own document. The code need not produce an identical graphic; anything similar containing a snaking line in such a U-shaped path will do.

[image: heating element in circuit diagram]

Comment: Basically you need to connect a bunch of 180 degree arcs., sort of like an american inductor (not fancy) only on both sides.  The big question is whether you want to create a shape, a pic, or a macro.

Comment: Would you please post a minimal circuit with your approach? It would be easier for us to help...

Comment: You can perceive the heating wire as (at least) two straight wires, which you decorate "twiggeling" with the decoration tikzlibrary. // See introduction and details in the huge manual at: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may need a draw-it-yourself solution. This can be done with the `decorations.pathreplacing` library using `show path construction` and defining a new path from the start point to the end point.

In the code below you can draw a heating element from one coordinate to another and specify the direction of the element as an angle (default=90). For example, `\draw[htr] (blk1)--(red1);` for the first image and `\draw[htr=0] (red2)--(blk2);` for the second.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    htr/.style={decoration={show path construction, 
        lineto code={\draw[looseness=1.3] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)node[dot]{}
            to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1-45:.3) to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1+45:.3)
            to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1-45:.3) to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1+45:.3) 
            to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1-45:.3) to[out=#1, in=#1+180] ++(#1+45:.3) 
            to[looseness=.7,out=#1, in=#1]
            ([shift={(#1:1.8/sqrt(2))}]\tikzinputsegmentlast)
            to[out=#1+180, in=#1] ++(#1+135:.3) to[out=#1+180, in=#1] ++(#1+225:.3)
            to[out=#1+180, in=#1] ++(#1+135:.3) to[out=#1+180, in=#1] ++(#1+225:.3)
            to[out=#1+180, in=#1] ++(#1+135:.3) to[out=#1+180, in=#1] (\tikzinputsegmentlast)node[dot]{};
        }}, decorate},
    htr/.default=90,
    dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw (0,0)--node[sloped, above, near end]{BLK}++(0,2)coordinate(blk1);
\draw (.8,0)--node[sloped, above, near end]{RED}++(0,2)coordinate(red1);
\draw[htr] (blk1)--(red1);

\draw (1,0)--node[sloped, above, near end]{BLK}++(2,0)coordinate(blk2);
\draw (1,.8)--node[sloped, above, near end]{RED}++(2,0)coordinate(red2);
\draw[htr=0] (red2)--(blk2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I will take a look at the `decorations.pathreplacing` library and this `++(#1+45:.3)` syntax that I am not familiar with to try to replicate this myself to learn how you came to this solution. It is great that your solution saves this `htr` "style" so that it may be re-used in different places. Thank you.

Comment: @JacobHouse: The notation `++(θ:r)` is a relative polar coordinate. The `++` means move from the previous position by the given coordinate. The `:` indicates a polar coordinate (angle first). `#1+45` means 45 degrees counterclockwise from the given direction `#1`, and the `.3` is the distance in `cm`.

Answer (score 4):

That kind of shape probably needs a "real" component. One approximation could be with a [decoration](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate(A) at (0,0); \coordinate(B) at (1,0);
    \node [circ, label=below:A] at (A){};
    \node [circ, label=below:B] at (B){};
    %\draw [red] (A) -- ++(0,3) -| (B);
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style={%
        decorate, decoration={coil, segment length=.4cm, aspect=0}}]
        \draw  (A) -- ++(0,3) coordinate(tmp);
        \draw  (tmp) -- (tmp-|B);
        \draw  (tmp-|B) -- (B) coordinate(tmp);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...although I struggled a lot with the decoration parameters; I suspect there is a strange "feature" going on:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=0.4cm}] (0,3/2) -- ++(1,0);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=0.5cm}] (0,2/2) -- ++(1,0);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=0.8cm}] (0,1/2) -- ++(1,0);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=1.0cm}] (0,0) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]